# Getting Error in Phonegap application in ios

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui

I am working kendoui mobile in phonegap ,i have cerated html page display list of records from dat base using wcf web api service  it is working fine in android but in iphone i am getting error PhoneGapSample[1672:15503] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://api.mybusinessapp.com/restaurant/ListOrder(0825CA34-CEFF-11E0-84C1-2F0C4824018B)'

help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

ERROR whitelist rejection means the url you are trying to access is not in the list of allowed external resources.

Go in your plist file and add mybusinessapp.com or just *